# When/How to solve this PLY Shift-Reduce conflict in parser generator for COOL language?

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, ply

I am making a compiler for the Cool: the Classroom Object-Oriented Language. I followed the manual [Cool-manual.pdf](https://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/software/cool/cool-manual.pdf) to create a grammar and using PLY 3.10 in python 3.5.2 I managed to create a lexer and a parser, but somehow it found a Shift-Reduce conflict on this production:

```
expr : LET ID COLON TYPE assign_optional let_assignments IN expr
```

**expr** is a Non-terminal symbol that produces several things, among them is the "LET...." above but, as this LET production ends with "...IN expr" that means that the LALR(1) parser from yacc do not know if it should SHIFT after that last **expr** with what comes after or REDUCE  that **expr**.

For instance:

That last expr could be something like:

```
a + 2
```

and as COOL allows I could also do this:

```
expr : expr + expr #that means expr produces expr PLUS expr
```

and therefore, after that last **expr** in the **LET** I could have a **+** (or anything allowed). For instance, in this line

```
LET a:Int <- 3 IN a + 2 + c
```

could mean to add **a + 2 + c** as the expression inside of the *LET* or to add **c** to the result of the *LET expression*.

My main issue is:

Should I redo the grammar to avoid this conflict? If i should, how would I do it? cause I think I am not doing anything wrong following the COOL specifications.

Else, Should I handle this on the Semantic Analysis Phase? Any thoughts on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.
I hope I explained myself. If not, please let me know and I will try to explain better.

Comment: ply implements the same kind of precedence based choice to shift vs reduce: http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why `let` is not in the list of expression precedences in section 11 of the manual, but section 7 says

> The `<expr>` of a `let` extends as far (encompasses as many tokens) as the grammar allows.

which is tantamount to saying that it has the lowest possible precedence (the same as assignment).

I presume you are using precedence declarations for your `expr` rules, so just add `let` to the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just got online now to answer my own question, because I figured out what to do. In fact, that quote from the manual says it all. I apparently skip that sentence. Cause that means, that I in fact have no problem at all, cause doing SHIFT if what I should do, and everything will be part of the LET's **expr** until specifically told otherwise

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX: Yes, the default will work for you. But if you want to eliminate the warning, adding a precedence declaration should do the job :)

Comment: Like adding LET to the **precedence** array?

Comment: @Dark_firefox now that I look at the Ply documentation, I think you should add the `IN` token to the precedence array, since that is the last token in the `let` rule. Or you could use a `%prec` declaration in the rule to name a different token (such as `<-`, which has the same precedence).